# Session value is changing during the execution of code

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working in an asp.net project.
I am storing values to session during the `Page_Load` in a `Master Page`. I am accessing these values in a `Web-UserControl`, which is placed in the template page (which inherits from the `MasterPage`).

Now the issue is i am not getting the session values in the user control properly.
While i executed the code in debug mode i came to know that i am getting the session value at the beginning of the function, but the **value is being cleared at the end of the function**. This is an absurd situation.

Have anyone faced this kind of issues?
Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: are you sure you are not changing the session value in your code somewhere ?

Comment: In visual Studio, Right-click on the `Session` object, and select `Find all references`. You will find any code that writes to the session state.

Comment: I haven't changed the session value in the code.